# Send contact form data to email and show success/failure message on same page

Tags: php

Email is working fine (Email is sending successfully) but when the user clicks on submit button it just redirects to the contact.php file. I want that when user will click on the button it will show the success message in the same HTML file just below or above the submit button and the message will also be sent. So can someone tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Below is the HTML code:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email *" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">           
        <textarea class="form-control textarea" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">           
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form-control btn-submit" Value="Send">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Below is my PHP Code:

```
<?php 
    ob_start();

 $name = $_POST['name'];

 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];


  $email_from ='';

  $email_subject = "Get In Touch";

  $email_body = "User Name: $name \n".
            "User Email: $email \n".
                "Phone Number: $phone \n".
                        "User Message: \n                           
  $message \n";

  $to = "myemail@gmail.com";

  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

  $headers = "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

  $result = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

  if($result) {
  echo "Thank You for contacting us. Our team will get back to you 
  shortly.";
  }

  else{
   echo "Something Went wrong. Please try again"; }
   ?>
```

Note: There are two separate files one for HTML code as 'index.html' and other for PHP code as 'contact.php'

Comment: You must learn Javascript

Answer (score 0):

When you submit form you can set action where you want to submit it (in your code you submit form to `contact.php`:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
```

If you don't want ro submit to another file you can write form in same file with your php script, for example (**all this code in contact.php**) and you should remove `contact.php` from action property of form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email *" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control textarea" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form-control btn-submit" Value="Send">
            </div>
        </form>

<?php

ob_start();

if (!empty($_POST)) {

 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];


  $email_from ='';

  $email_subject = "Get In Touch";

  $email_body = "User Name: $name \n".
            "User Email: $email \n".
                "Phone Number: $phone \n".
                        "User Message: \n
  $message \n";

  $to = "myemail@gmail.com";

  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

  $headers = "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

  $result = true;

  if($result) {
      echo "Thank You for contacting us. Our team will get back to you
      shortly.";
  } else {
    echo "Something Went wrong. Please try again";
  }
}
```

But this is not very good option, other option is to use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)